# Basic CoffeeScript not firing events when run?

Tags: coffeescript, backbone.js

I'm having real problems writing a simple Backbone.js app using CoffeeScript and Zepto.js

This is the simplest Backbone view yet the events don't fire. I get no errors in the console either? Where am I going wrong?

```
#Main view
class AppView extends Backbone.View

  constructor: ->    
    @el = $("#books")    
    @template = _.template("<div>New Item <a href='' id='addNew'> add new item</a></div>")

  events: {
      "click" : "createNew"
  }

  render: =>
    @el.html(@template())

  createNew : ->
    console.log "new"


#Onload
$(document).ready ->
   view = new AppView
   view.render()
```

I've been following the only example I can find of CoffeeScript & Backbone together https://github.com/bnolan/Backbone-Mobile/blob/master/application.coffee

However if I add super into my view code above I get an undefined error, his code does not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class `Backbone.View` has its own `constructor` that does plenty of work, and you are overriding it and not calling `super`. Bad.

Instead, `Backbone.View` provides you the ability to define your own constructor-type function called `initialize`. Perform all your setup there. `Backbone.View#constructor` will call `initialize`.

```
#Main view
class AppView extends Backbone.View

  initialize: ->    
    @el = $("#books")    
    @template = _.template(
      "<div>New Item <a href='' id='addNew'> add new item</a></div>"
    )
```

Comment: Yes your totally right. There should be no reason to use constructor or super in this instance.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem (events not firing) and found that the problem was due to not setting @el. I set that:

```
@el: $("#content")
```

and it worked.